# How to use mongodb changestream processing in scalable and fault tolerant probably live-livefashion

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am using mongodb changestream which listen for change in collection as per particular match logic. https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/27/what-s-new-in-spring-data-lovelace-for-mongodb

While the above works great but I am not sure how we can make above processing resilient and scalable. I tried to search around above but I could not find any solution around that.

How can we start multiple thread/process listening for a change as per same match criteria so that we can process change in parallel and also ensure change for a particular key get picked up by same thread/process to prevent out of order processing like Kafka partition so that application can be resilient and scalable as well.

Thanks for answering my question